# A black girl married a vampire prince

Tags: story-identification, novel, vampire

I read a really good book about a poor black girl living in a village ruled by vampires. She ends up being his destined person in an accidental ceremony. They marry but have problems because he can't have anyone else's blood and they can't get along.

Comment: You might have better help if you can tell us the era of the book (is it a modern village, or a dark ages village, etc.?), and the publish date of the book (was it brand new 5 years ago, or did you read it in the 70s as a kid?). Right now, Google searches for girls marrying vampire princes are turning up a lot of amateur stories and fan fiction. [This](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13509885-accidentally-married-to-a-vampire) is the closest I could find.

Comment: About the book... Is it Ardis Chedore's The Book of the Underworld? Found it while searching and it has a lot of triggers like rape and beating and I'm kinda scared to go down to that kind of google search again.

Comment: Sounds a little like [Octavia Butler's *Fledging.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fledgling_%28novel%29)

Comment: Or part of [Jewelle Gomez's *The Gilda Stories.*](http://www.amazon.com/The-Gilda-Stories-Jewelle-Gomez/dp/1563411407)

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about but I can remember the name of it at all the girl was hired by a noble to be her servant to get the princes attention and stand out since her people were seen as wild and exotic but then it turns out that she has to marry the prince because the moon goddess put a curse not the princes family or something she was also Engadged with someone else before this and he wanted to kill the people who rule their land now and is going to have her do it for him and he ends up changing to be a very cruel person I just found it I think it's called queen of blood

Answer (score 2):

Is this *[The Darkangel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/92717.The_Darkangel)* by Meredith Ann Pierce?  Published in 1983.

Aeriel is a servant to Eoduin. They live in a small village. One day while out gathering flowers Eoduin is taken by the darkangel (also called vampyre or icarus) to be his thirteenth bride. He drains their souls and they stay in his castle as wraiths. Aeriel tries to save Eoduin but is also taken by the vampyre. He makes her work as his wives' servant (tirewoman). When the darkangel is unable to find a 14th woman to be his bride, he decides to marry Aeriel even though

> "You are not as pretty as some of my wives have been," he remarked,
>   shrugging, "but you will do."

This is because she isn't as pale as the other wives.  However Aeriel is not quite described as black in the book:

> She gazed longingly at her well-born mistress's hair, black as the
>   heavens, with a blue sheen by earthlight. Eoduin's skin, pale and blue
>   as breastmilk, had a subtle radiance that gleamed even in shadow. But
>   Aeriel, slighter than her companion by a head, was boy-shaped still,
>   her skin deeper-shaded : a wan rose-tan that even bleaching with
>   lightning weed could not expunge.

With the help of the duarough* she meets at the castle, Aeriel is able to break the enchantment on the darkangel.  There are two sequels, A gathering of Gargoyles and The pearl of the soul of the world.

*Dwarf. The author seemed to enjoy spelling words slightly differently, maybe to emphasise how otherworldly this place is. After a while it got a bit tedious!

Comment: The original wording of the question described the girl as “colored.” Maybe the OP used that word to mean a lighter skin tone, although that isn’t generally how it’s used.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the original wording, "black" is not a word I would usually use to describe skin tone, but it was what the question used so was what I addressed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the deleted answer by Lizzyh, this is likely *[Queen of Blood](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25750114-queen-of-blood)* by Jill Myles, or possibly the original story, *[Betrothed](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18006867-betrothed)*, which was rewritten and rebranded as *Queen of Blood*. The Goodreads summary of "Betrothed* (emphasis mine):

> For years, Seri’s simple people have lived under the thumb of the Athonites, a regal, erudite caste. She wants no part of politics, though; she simply wants to live in peace. But when she’s given the opportunity to work at the enemy’s castle, she takes it, not realizing that she is sealing her own fate.
>
> Prince Graeme is surprised to see the wild girl at court acting as a servant. He’s even more surprised when, **during an important ceremony, she is decreed as his chosen bride** – his Betrothed. As his Betrothed, she will give something long denied those of his lineage: relief from his age-old secret curse.
>
> As kingdoms come to war and Seri’s people begin an uprising, she will have to pick sides. Will she choose her own folk…or the mysterious prince that is slowly stealing her heart?

[image: Book cover]

Goodreads notes it as vampire fiction and the summary for *Queen of Blood* mentions the curse.

> The Blood are powerful and immortal, but doomed to live in the shadows, flitting from lover to lover, always in search of the mythic Eterna—the one woman who will sate their hunger.

The cover images don't match with the girl having dark skin, but that's not uncommon. She is apparently of the "Viradi" people, and the two chapter free sample I grabbed off of Amazon mentions she has "brown skin".